# vlc saves an empty file when using the video cropping filter

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

When I use the cropadd filter:[image]

everything works until the final screen:[image]

If i click "save" I get an 1KB file

If i don't use this "video cropping filter" I get a new file that has nothing cropped (i.e.: it is the same as the input file)